# sass go to declaration

Tags: css, ide, editor, sass

Does anyone know any editor that supports "go to declaration" for mixins, functions, variables in sass?

PHPStorm claims to, but it only works if the declarations are in the same file, not if they are imported from an external file.

Cheers

UPDATE:
Turns out [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) does this out of the box!

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible by using the *ctags* [language configuration](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html) option to configure a sass language definition and then use any editor that [supports](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/tools.html) ctags. On the Windows platform I use the Zeus editor from that *list of editors* and it works nicely with ctags.

Comment: Hmmm would prefer not to have to write my own, but maybe there's no other option!

Comment: The option that high5 describes above does not require any writing of code. What he is describing is a configuration step and requires nothing more than a few regular expressions.